# Populate VO in drop down list in UI

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have Person class which is root of its aggregate, this aggregate also contains country and state province as vo.

{Person, Country, StateProvince} - > Person is root aggregate.

//
Public Person(string name, string country, state province,{other params}){}

**// But now i am facing problem in UI, how will i populate Dropdown for Country and Stateprovince, through person because it is root aggregate, but i don't want any person's assigned Country or Stateprovince but i want list of all countries and their Stateprovince, so that user choose one from them**

**Do i manually create table for country and stateprovince and fill them with all values manually.If yes, then how will i get values from those tables in ddd .**

Comment: @Nilesh I've suggested a edit/rewrite of question. I think what is confusing the poster is how to determine aggregate boundaries.  It can be confusing without seeing some concrete examples.  I've reworded it to make that more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i have lookup function for VO in Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478009/can-i-have-lookup-function-for-vo-in-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model is trying to tell you something.

> Country and StateProvince are probably not part of the Person Aggregate.

Remember the very handy "delete test" for an aggregate, ask if I delete this person do I also delete their country and StateProvince?  I live in Canada, and you remove me from your system are you also going to delete the country Canada from your system as well?

No, you would not.  You have **two** separate aggregates here Person and Location which would contain the Aggregate of {Country, StateProvince}  If you delete a country you would very likely also delete all the states or provinces contained within it as well.

Just because Person references a class or *has-a* class doesn't make all the references part of that aggregate. Location is very common aggregate in many systems and regularly stands on it's own.

You should have a Person Repository that utilizes a LocationRepository and have the UI directly call the LocationRepository to obtain Location Aggregates.

Comment: If i delete a person , then in my understanding if you are deleting a person say John, you are deleting entry of john and the association of john with country which is in separate table. I am maintaining table of country and state province in separate table. S o when i delete John i will delete entry from base table of Person and the entry from table that has relation between John and country, but not in separate table of Country and StateProvince.

Comment: HandlingHistory lookupHandlingHistoryOfCargo(TrackingId trackingId)

This is a function from Evan's sample project, We can see that this function returns HandlingHistory which is vo in HandlingEvent aggregate. Can I too have similar kind of look up for country and stateprovince in person agg.

Comment: i agree with your comment that i should have Location as a separate aggregate, but there are times where for a simple VO you don't want to create separate aggregate and repository. So can we have look up function just like i mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You would populate your country and state province from different tables. You would then fill the drop downs from these tables. When working with a specific Person entity which has already got Country and StateProvince assigned you would bind them with master tables through id.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How will i populate, where do i write retrieval functions, in Person repository, but according to my understanding repository only gives root agg

Comment: @kamai generally you'd populate the tables as part of the seed data for the system.  By manually entering all countries and their respective states and provinces, or obtaining this data through a 3rd party. For example the US Postal Service offers US state and zip data for a fee, http://www.usps.com/ncsc/addressinfo/addressinfomenu.htm?from=zclsearch&page=ais I'm sure there are other vendors supporting more countries as well.  But location data is either manually entered or bought unless you do something fancy with crowdsourcing it like a foursquare and let your users add Locations.